# VS2008 Debug ASP and ASP.net together

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, debugging

Is there any way to debug both classic ASP and ASP.net applications from visual studio to allow me to breakpoint on an ASP line of code and an ASP.net one too?

This is for a legacy system which has older classic asp components and newer ASP.net modules

I have it working by debugging the ASP.net on its own (and not the ASP) or the other way around by debugging the ASP (and not the ASP.net)

To do ASP:

Attach to process w3wp.exe from within Visual Studio (as the site is hosted on IIS7 on my local windows 7 x64 machine)

To do ASP.net:

Goto VS Site properties and choose default server.

Is what I want to do possible?

Thanks

MH

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a simple No I'm afraid.  You can not attach to a process to debug both Script and Managed Code at the same time.