# How can I debug a classic ASP page in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, visual-studio-2019

I have an ASP.NET web app with some classic ASP pages mixed in and I was hoping to step through the code for some of those pages, but when I set breakpoints in them, they never get hit; if I hover over them I see "breakpoint set but not yet bound". Is there any way to debug classic ASP pages in VS2019?

edit: A few of my aspx (ASP.NET) pages get this breakpoint error too; I'm not sure why some of the breakpoints work and others don't...

Comment: Hmm, I tried enabling server side debugging in IIS as that link says, but now I get a different error with the breakpoints: "No symbols have been loaded for this document". Could this have something to do with the fact that my app is a hybrid of classic ASP and ASP.NET?

Comment: The key is to make sure the debugger is attached to `Script` not compiled code.

Comment: And now all of a sudden I can debug classic ASP code, but I can't debug ASP.NET code anymore... How can I switch back?

Comment: When you attach to the process select both `Script` and `Managed` code types.

Comment: OK, I tried that but I get an error saying Managed and Script can't be selected at the same time because they're not compatible...

Comment: I guess not then, either way [asking another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57526327/692942) isn't going to help and just clutters the unanswered queue until someone provides [the same answer from 10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062919/692942).