# How can I debug both classic ASP and ASP.NET code in the same debugger session?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-2019

I have a web app which is a mix of classic ASP and ASP.NET code, and I'd like to use the debugger. However it seems from looking at the Modules window in Visual Studio that only the ASP code happens to be available to the debugger at the moment; I get "the breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document" when I set a breakpoint in the ASP.NET code. How do I make both the ASP and ASP.NET code available? Or failing that, how do I switch between the two? Earlier I was able to debug the ASP.NET code but not the ASP code; it seems to be switching back and forth somehow but I don't know how to force it to do so...

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062815/vs2008-debug-asp-and-asp-net-together) it's not possible to debug both ASP and ASP.NET in the same session, but that was 10 years ago so maybe something has changed?

Comment: So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511414/how-can-i-debug-a-classic-asp-page-in-visual-studio-2019#comment101521426_57511414) didn't help?

Comment: No, I get an error saying I can't select Managed and Script at the same time because they're not compatible somehow.

Comment: Classic ASP is old technology it hasn't changed in over 20 years, so if an [answer from 10 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062919/692942) says its not possible then I'd go with that.

Comment: Does it have to be in the same debugger session? Can you not simply launch two VS instances and have one debug managed code and the other classic ASP?

Comment: I suppose I could try that, though it feels really awkward...